# How to flush the dataLayer variable which is persistent across two tags?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I have some issues on my client website or say dataLayer persistence issue.

For e.g. On a page, when I click on 1st tag, let's name it A, the dataLayer fires correctly.

Next when I click on 2nd tag, lets name it B, the dataLayer fires correctly.

But when I go and click on Tag A again, the dataLayer has the value of Tag B, Its quite persistence across many websites(client).

I have tried `window.google_tag_manager[{{Container ID}}].dataLayer.reset();` but its not what serves my purpose.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I have same problem. Did you find any solution?